# Why do I get an error while coding the constructor?

Tags: flutter

I have the following code and it gives an error:

> The parameter 'product' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

here is my code:

```dart
final Product product;
 const ItemCard({
   Key? key,
   this.product, // error here
 }): super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the 'required' keyword before product.

Consider writing as follows:

```
final Product _product;

 const ItemCard({Key? key, required Product product}) :
_product = product, super(key: key);
```

These are changes resulting from null safety [link](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: and also you can avoid "required" option from constructor by using, final Product? _product; when declare the variable. hope it will be helped

Answer (score 0):

here:

```dart
final Product product;
const ItemCard({
  Key? key,
  Product myProduct,
}):
  product = myProduct,
  super(key: key);
```

Comment: Outside of different variable names, and some slight syntactical differences, this is functionally identical to the [previous answer by @Kdon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67914203/3025856). Please be sure to review existing answers before submitting a new one, and only add a new answer if you have a different approach, or can offer a better explanation of a similar approach.